# Execute handleClick multiple times

Tags: reactjs, promise

I have a Button which does a POST request when it's clicked. While waiting for the response I have a Loading animation. However now I want this button not to only make 1 post request I want it to do 100 post requests with 1 click

My Button

```
          <Form>
              <Form.Group>
                <Button variant='success' className='button' onClick={handleClick} id='create'>Create Sales Order</Button>
              </Form.Group>
         </Form>
```

My Loader while waiting for the API Call

```
            <BeatLoader
              css={override}
              size={30}
              // size={"150px"} this also works
              color='#b51a82'
              loading={isLoading}
            />
```

this is the handleClick function which gets called when the button is pressed

```
 async function handleClick (event) {
  switch (event.target.id) {
    case 'create':
      setLoading(true)
      break

    case 'delete':
      // code for delete case
      break

    default:
      console.log('click didnt work')
  }
}
```

my useEffect Hook. In this hook I tried to put the content of the createSalesOrder function in a loop, which does not work because it will break my loading animation (the loading animation will not stop)

```
useEffect(() => {

  async function createSalesOrder () {
    const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/')
    console.log(res)
    setValue([...value, res.data])
    return (res)
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    createSalesOrder().then(() => {
      setLoading(false)
    })
  }
}, [isLoading])
```

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the question? Is the problem that you want to click the button multiple times but have it loading until the all of the orders have been created?

Comment: Have you tried to fetch it 100 times with [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)?

Comment: Hi Tom, I editet the orignal question. The problem is I want to click the button 1 time and make it do 100 post requests. @Pawel No I have not, to be honest I don't realy understand how Promise.all works

Comment: if you just wanna do more requests, just put a loop in the `createSalesOrder` func like ``` async function createSalesOrder () {
   let newValue = [...value]
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/')
      newValue.push(res.data)
    }
    return newValue
  }
```

Comment: Updated my answer with an additional note. If you need the promises to resolve in order, where the second waits for the first to resolve, etc, then you'll need a very different solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for one or more promises to complete. It returns a single promise that "wraps" all of the other promises which will resolve when all of the promises have resolved, or reject immediately if any one of the promises is rejected.

If you want to want to wait for all of the promises to finish, even if some are rejected, then use [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

```
useEffect(() => {

  async function createSalesOrder () {
    const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/')
    console.log(res)
    setValue([...value, res.data])
    return (res)
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    const finished = _ => setLoading(false);

    // Wait for all of the sales orders to finish
    Promise.all(
      // Create an array of 100 promises:

      // Quickly create an array with 100 entries
      [...Array(100).keys()].map(

        // For each entry, submit a request to create a sales order
        // and return a promise
        createSalesOrder
      )
    ).then(
      // When all of the promises have resolved, end your animation:
      finished,
      // Make sure you stop the animation even if an error occurred:
      finished
    );
  }
}, [isLoading])
```

Also, keep in mind that the promises will be resolved/rejected in whatever order they come back from the server, not necessarily in the order they were sent out. This means that it is totally possible that the first order you created will be resolved somewhere in the middle, that the last order you created will be resolved first, etc., and that if you repeat the logic, the order in which they are resolved will be different each and every time.